# swift: change option 'section header" of UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

when I add a `UICollectionView` to my `ViewController` in the Storyboard, there is a checkbox labeled **"Section Header"**, how can I trigger that option programmatically(using an outlet of the CollectionView)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should register the HeaderView you want to use in your CollectionView like this

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: HCollectionReusableView.nibName, bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HCollectionReusableView")
```

And after that you can call in your `UICollectionViewDataSource` implementation, the function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let reusableview = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HCollectionReusableView", for: indexPath) as! HCollectionReusableView

            reusableview.frame = CGRect(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, headerHight)
     //do other header related calls or settups
            return reusableview
        default:  
            fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```